# running mkvirtualenv using ansible

Tags: virtualenv, ansible

I am provisioning a machine using ansible. I managed to install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper fine on the vm. However, I can't seem to create a virtualenv on the vm.

I am trying using

```
- name: create virtualenv test
  shell: >
    executable=/bin/zsh
    source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh` && mkvirtualenv test
  register: run_cmd
```

and

```
- name: create virtualenv test
  action: command mkvirtualenv test
```

but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source only adds  virtualenvwrappers to the shell its invoked in, which you then exit immediately.  In any case, I would not use virtualenvwrapper for this.  Invoke `virtualenv` directly.

Answer (score 14):

You can create an environment using mkvirtualenv like this. I was hoping to be able to use the `toggleglobalsitepackages`, but I found that toggling is not so convenient in an automated session.

```
- name: Make a virtualenv
  shell: . /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv {{ venv }}
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
    creates: "{{ venvabs }}"
```

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to @SiggyF's excellent answer, I would like to add: In case that it appears that this ansible task fails, as it happens somehow with me, you can use the `failed_when` feature (ansible 1.4+):

```
- name: Make virtualenv
  shell: "./usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv {{ project }} --python={{ python }} --no-site-packages"
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
    creates: "{{ virtualenv_dir }}/{{ project }}"
  register: mkvirtualenv
  failed_when: 'mkvirtualenv.changed and "New python executable" not in mkvirtualenv.stdout'
```