# Virtualenvwrapper mkvirtualenv command not found via ansible shell

Tags: ansible, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I want to create a virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper via ansible.
My default vars:

```
wrapper_bin: '/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
virtualenv_dir: '/home/user/.envs'
```

`{{ project_name }}` comes from extra variable

My task:

```
---
- name: Make a virtualenv
  shell: "{{ wrapper_bin }} && mkvirtualenv {{ project_name }}"
  args:
     executable: /bin/bash
     creates: "{{ virtualenv_dir}}/{{ project_name }}"
```

On a remote machine all works well.
`which virtualenvwrapper.sh` returns correct way `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`
But Ansible throw an error `/bin/bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running mkvirtualenv using ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960944/running-mkvirtualenv-using-ansible)

Answer (score 2):

Add `PATH` to the environment, for example:

```
---
- name: Make a virtualenv
  shell: "{{ wrapper_bin }} && mkvirtualenv {{ project_name }}"
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
    creates: "{{ virtualenv_dir}}/{{ project_name }}"
  environment:
    path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

It is one of the most common problems with Ansible - it runs shell non-interactive, non-logon session which by shell design does not source all the rc-files. In result the `PATH` you have when logged on interactively and the `PATH` Ansible gets in its environment differ.

Comment: thanks but still the same error: `/bin/bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Make a virtualenv
  shell: export PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH mkvirtualenv {{ project_name }}
```

If you use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
- name: Create the required virtualenv
  shell: |
    export WORKON_HOME="{{ virtualenv_dir }}"
    export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
    . /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
    mkvirtualenv "{{project_name}}" -p python3.6
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
    creates: "{{ virtualenv_dir}}/{{ project_name }}"
  register: appServer_virtualenv
  become_user: "{{sudo_user}}"
```