# How to create virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper in Ansible

Tags: ansible, virtualenvwrapper

How to create virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper within ansible module. Without using shell command and using mkvirtualenv command

I tried using mkvirtualenv as one of the tasks in ansible playbook

```
- name: Run virtualenvwrapper commands to create a virtualenv
    mkvirtualenv: "/home/miniconda3/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
    virtualenv: test
```

This is not a duplicate as I need to know if there is any ansible module for virtualenvwrapper commands like "mkvirtualenv". This is not about using shell  commands in an ansible playbook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running mkvirtualenv using ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960944/running-mkvirtualenv-using-ansible)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible+virtualenvwrapper

Comment: There is no `mkvirtualenv`  `ansible` module that I'm aware of(?).

Comment: Not a duplicate. My goal is to find an ansible module, not shell commands